# Entity Framework Core - error: keyword not supported: '"server'

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.1. I scaffold my entity classes aka database first. When I try to get the data from one of the db tables, I get an error "keyword not supported for 'server'."

I googled and it looks like my connection string is not correct. Here it is setting in my json file

```
"DefaultConnection": "\"Server=myDb.com;Database=MyDb;user id=admin;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Provider=System.Data.SqlClient"
```

I have seen other type of EF connection like

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=test;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

I am not sure about the .csdl, ssdl and msl.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Error:

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: '"server'.
>
> at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
>   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](IEnumerable`1 results, QueryContext queryContext, IList`1 entityTrackingInfos, IList`1 entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>   Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
>   'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.2\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   The program '[3112] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Answer (score 3):

Simple removing \" from front and end of connection string will work. In this case you can use complete connection string.

```
"DefaultConnection": "\"Server=tcp:myDb.com,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=admin;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"\;"
```

to

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=myDb.com,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=admin;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

Answer (score 1):

After playing with different connection string, here what I changed in my json to file to get it working

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=myDb.com;Database=MyDb;user id=admin;Password=Password;
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how an incomplete connection string would solve your problem. The part you show is the same as above.

Comment: Actually it is slightly different in that the character escapes have been removed. I had the same issue after adding an identity using an existing dbContext and conn string

Answer (score 0):

This is because the connection strings have been replaced after scaffolding the identity. The replacement string may look very similar but has some escaped characters in it.

I had `appSettings.Development.json`, `appSettings.Staging.json` and `appSettings.Production.json`, each with DIFFERENT connection strings.

After scaffolding my Identity using an EXISTING dbContext, it had replaced the connection string in appSettings.json files with the one single connection string. I have no idea why it picked that one but I realised the string was escaped so

```
"Server=MYCOMPNAME\\SQLEXPRESS;...
```

had become

```
"\"Server=KRYTEN\\\\SQLEXPRESS;
```

and this is why we get the error.